# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'print' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing

I have implemented Print functionality where a new print window will open upon click of a button. Due to change in requirement, I commented it out and everything was going fine. Client wanted to have the printing functionality again. So, I just uncommented

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'print' of undefined

I cleared cache, repackaged everything and redeployed. Nothing is helping me fix this. Can you please let me know where I am doing wrong.

**UPDATE**

Guys,

I was using the following code to print it.

```
myWindow=window.open(url, "myWindow", "width=2000, height=1000");       
    myWindow.print();
```

I figured out the problem. The popup was blocked. Once I allowed the popup, it worked fine.

Comment: please add some code. thanks.

Comment: How can we fix it if you don't show us where the problem is?

Comment: Yes. The thing you did wrong was uncommenting that code. Furthermore I believe you also asked for help without giving enough information. Consider the following question: "I looked outside and saw something that I could not believe, why did I see that?"

Comment: @JK, If someone is lazy, then they do not even put effort to ask questions. Do not think that you are the most clever in the world. People make mistakes and I accepted what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Popup was blocked and so I was getting this error. Once I allowed the popup, it worked fine.